# Https Man-in-the-middle will happen in my scene?

Tags: https

There's a scene confused me: If I intercept the request, And I send the my CA which is official to client, it can through the verification from client? And This mitm would go on?

Answer (score 0):

MITM means exact what you say. You have a intermediate component that plays as a client for the end server and as the end server for the original client.

Your MITM component establishes a connection to the end server in a regular ssl manner - hence it knows all the response properties of a server. It then encrypts the data with its own private key and sends the response further on to the original client with new fake certificate generated for the same subject as the original service address.

It signs generated certificate with your custom CA private key.

Since your custom CA root cert is trusted by the client, the client will accept the certificate from your MITM and won't report any issue.

Comment: From your answer, it is very easy for me to play mitm attack when someone connect to my WiFi?

Comment: If that someone would have your CA certificate installed to their trust store - yes.

Comment: No need to install my CA, If my CA is generated from official channel which means my CA is already trusted by someone's device. Right?

Comment: What is official channel ? CA is is basically a key pair that is used to sign/verify issued certificates. If you have own one, there is no chance an arbitrary client has it installed.

Comment: Client verify CA is from some root organization, I mean my CA is generated from these organizations, so the client trust my CA and will verified. Isn't it?

Comment: Does [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255634/could-having-intermediate-ca-not-installed-to-trust-store-be-a-vulnerability) help?

Comment: Yes. It helps me a lot. It confused me a long time that a domain can or can't be in different public CA. And than u again